# Webdriver Manager for chrome 119

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, webdriver-manager

I am facing Following Error in Webdriver Manager:

```
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\http.py", line 37, in get
    self.validate_response(resp)
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\webdriver_manager\core\http.py", line 16, in validate_response
    raise ValueError(f"There is no such driver by url {resp.url}")
ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_119.0.6045
```

My Code is as follows:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/')
```

How to resolve it?